# Получать данные для автопостинга из многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Пытаюсь написать скрипт автопостинга на свою страницу FB.

И не могу сообразить, как мне брать скриптом поочередно массивы данных для постинга из, видимо, многомерного массива, в котором хранятся заранее подготовленные данные для публикаций (текст, изображение и, возможно, ссылка).

Не знаю, правильно ли это. Но я хочу совместить конструкцию switch ... case  с массивом данных, которые нужно публиковать.

**Как "засунуть" switch case в массив, из которого скрипт постинга будет брать данные?**

В общем, есть две такие части кода:

Это в первом приближении постинг:

```
<?php
    $app_id = '1234567890'; // для примера пусть будет таким
    $app_secret = '2345678901';
    $access_token = '3456789012';
    $page_id = '4567890123';

    ........... тут еще данные для входа на Fb.......

    // Непосредственно постим:

    $post = [
        'message' => 'Текст',
        'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/полный/путь/к/картинке'),
    ];
    $batch = [
        'photo' => $fb->request('POST', "/{$page_id}/photos", $post),
    ];
    $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
?>
```

НО, поскольку мне требуется именно АВТОпостинг по расписанию, то данные в $post при каждом запуске скрипта нужно брать поочередно из некоего массива $arr. Пока самый упрощенный вариант:

```
<?php
j=0;

switch(j) { 
    case 0:
        $message = $arr[0];
        break;
    case 1:
        $message = $arr[1];
        break;

    case 2:
        $message = $arr[2];
        break;
    case 3:
        $message = $arr[3];
        break;
    case 4:
        $message = $arr[4];
        break;
}
?>
```

И тут мой мозг иссяк. Не могу понять, как мне объединить эти куски.
Я с многомерными массивами дела не имела раньше.

**Можно ли положить мои элементы массива $arr из switch case в массив $post[]?**

Как это сделать?
Спасибо!

P.S. 
 ***может, здесь лучше использовать функцию next()? Буду признательна за пример кода для таких случаев***

Comment: что в и тоге какой массив должен получиться

Comment: есть слияние массивов, есть array_push, добавить значение, можно организовать в цикле. потренируйся на простых массивах слияние, добавить в конец массива другое значение. можно результат писать в файл с датой  временем для тренировки очерёдности итд

Comment: Вопрос в том, как брать из родительского массива по одному дочернему массиву за один раз. И при следующем запуске скрипта брать следующий дочерний массив

Comment: есть циклы, есть условия, кто запускает скрипт, или просто отработать все значения в массиве за раз, без задержки итд, мног нюансов много решений, погугли велосипед уже изобретён

Comment: Думаю, что все гораздо проще. Сейчас нашла функцию next() - это, насколько я поняла, именно то, что мне нужно. А гуглить можно тогда, когда знаешь, как предметно сформулировать вопрос. Иначе можно год гуглить

Comment: Как работает автопостинг? С крона?

Comment: Walfter, да, планировщиком хочу запускать

Comment: Тогда по времени и смотреть какое сообщение отправлять? Нет?

Comment: Вот, я и решаю, как мне это лучше сделать. Или по времени, или переменную добавлять и изменять ее при каждом запуске. И тогда от ее значения отталкиваться

Comment: От времени отталкивайтесь и всё